# How to disable upstream proxy based on request.url in mitmproxy

Tags: mitmproxy

Is it possible to disable upstream proxy in Mitmproxy for request based on request properties (for example URL)?

Comment: Have you checked this example plugin? [change_upstream_proxy.py](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/06bab7026e71a24a74b918600e7f2c2ee50a9539/examples/contrib/change_upstream_proxy.py)

Comment: Yes, but it will change proxy for all next requests